# Discord.js moving person to random VoiceChannel

Tags: discord.js

I'm making a discord bot that will has a feature to move user's to a random voice channel if they want. I searched the internet 3 hours straight and checked the whole documentation. But still can't find anything.

note : I know this bot idea looks useless. But that's what I need.

code :

```
let voiceChannels = message.guild.filter(g => **idk how to check if it's vc** );
```

that's what I just found in 3 hours.

Comment: What's `message.guild`?

Comment: @GalAbra that's the Guild where the message comes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to access the guild's channels and then choose a random channel of type voice.

So in your case, it'd be:

```js
let voiceChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.filter((channel) => channel.type === "voice").random();
if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.reply("User is not in a voice channel");
await message.member.voice.setChannel(voiceChannel);
```